# Powershell Unhide Folder

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell App Toolkit to package up an application deployment. I am uninstalling previous version and installing the new version.

The issue is that the uninstaller is a hidden folder in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{9A558293-3B60-4C8F-8FAF-80A1DBC4512B}
```

What command can I add to Unhide the uninstall folder before kicking in the Pre-Installation Step?

Pre-Installation Step:

```
Execute-Process -Path "$envProgramFilesX86\InstallShield Installation Information\{FFF49E64-0ACC-4CC0-8E37-BAE63AACF1C5}\setup.exe" -Parameters "-runfromtemp -l0x0409  -removeonly"
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about variable `$envProgramFilesX86`? Do you mean `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to see the file you could use:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force
```

Otherwise, you can use attrib to change the attributes:

```
attrib "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information{9A558293-3B60-4C8F-8FAF-80A1DBC4512B}\setup.exe" -s -h
```

Comment: so something like this:

Execute-Process -Path attrib "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information{9A558293-3B60-4C8F-8FAF-80A1DBC4512B}\setup.exe -s -h" -Parameters "-runfromtemp -l0x0409  -removeonly"

Getting Error When Running This

Comment: Start-Process ( Get-ChildItem -Force "<Path to file>" ) -parameters

Comment: Or you can run the attrib command before you run your execute-process which will take the hidden attribute off the file. To set it back just change the -h to +h

Comment: So this is not for just one file, the whole folder is hidden. When I run the script it error out because the folder is hidden.

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{9A558293-3B60-4C8F-8FAF-80A1DBC4512B}"**


Start-Process ( Get-ChildItem -Force "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{9A558293-3B60-4C8F-8FAF-80A1DBC4512B}" ) -parameters "-s -h"

Execute-Process -Path "$envProgramFilesX86\InstallShield Installation Information\{FFF49E64-0ACC-4CC0-8E37-BAE63AACF1C5}\setup.exe" -Parameters "-runfromtemp -l0x0409  -removeonly"

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: I am good to go guys, I found another way of doing this. I just copied the files in the hidden folder and ran my uninstaller script and it works. But I did learn how to unhide folders, so thank you again.